# How to remove rows with inf from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very large dataframe(**df**) with approximately 35-45 columns(variables) and rows greater than 300. Some of the rows contains NA,NaN,Inf,-Inf values in single or multiple variables and I have used 
`na.omit(df)` to remove rows with NA and NaN but I cant remove rows with Inf and -Inf values using **na.omit** function.

While searching I came across this thread [Remove rows with Inf and NaN in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22804473/remove-rows-with-inf-and-nan-in-r) and used the modified code `df[is.finite(df)]` but its not removing the rows with Inf and -Inf and also gives this error

> Error in is.finite(df) : default method not implemented for type
>   'list'

EDITED

**Remove the entire row even the corresponding one or multiple columns have inf and -inf**

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To remove the rows with +/-`Inf` I'd suggest the following:

```
df <- df[!is.infinite(rowSums(df)),]
```

or, equivalently,

```
df <- df[is.finite(rowSums(df)),]
```

The second option (the one with `is.finite()` and without the negation) removes also rows containing `NA` values in case that this has not already been done.

Comment: This won't handle NA's. `NA+Inf` gives `NA` and `is.infinite(NA)` returns `FALSE`.

Comment: I thought the OP stated that NA's had already been take care of...?

Comment: Guess the second solution is more robust and should handle `NA` better.

Comment: @nicola Thank you for pointing out the difference between `!is.infinite()` and `is.finite()`. I learned something today ;-)

Comment: @jogo I think that one has to check in any case every element of the data.frame. In view of this, taking the sum with the vectorized function `rowSums()` should not be particularly time-consuming.

Answer (score 28):

Depending on the data, there are a couple options using scoped variants of `dplyr::filter()` and `is.finite()` or `is.infinite()` that might be useful:

```
library(dplyr)

# sample data
df <- data_frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, NA), b = c(5, Inf, 8, 8), c = c(9, 10, Inf, 11), d = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))

# across all columns:
df %>% 
  filter_all(all_vars(!is.infinite(.)))

# note that is.finite() does not work with NA or strings:
df %>% 
  filter_all(all_vars(is.finite(.)))

# checking only numeric columns:
df %>% 
  filter_if(~is.numeric(.), all_vars(!is.infinite(.)))

# checking only select columns, in this case a through c:
df %>% 
  filter_at(vars(a:c), all_vars(!is.infinite(.)))
```

Answer (score 11):

The `is.finite` works on `vector` and not on `data.frame` object.  So, we can loop through the `data.frame` using `lapply` and get only the 'finite' values.

```
lapply(df, function(x) x[is.finite(x)])
```

If the number of `Inf`, `-Inf` values are different for each column, the above code will have a `list` with elements having unequal `length`.  So, it may be better to leave it as a `list`.  If we want a `data.frame`, it should have equal lengths.

---

If we want to remove rows contain any NA or Inf/-Inf values

```
df[Reduce(`&`, lapply(df, function(x) !is.na(x)  & is.finite(x))),]
```

Or a compact option by @nicola

```
df[Reduce(`&`, lapply(df, is.finite)),]
```

---

If we are ready to use a package, a compact option would be `NaRV.omit`

```
library(IDPmisc)
NaRV.omit(df)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:5, NA, -Inf, Inf), 
                      20*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
```

Comment: The resultend output is not in a dataframe I tried like this `dim(df) 330 40 df2<-lapply(df, function(x) x[is.finite(x)])   dim(df2)  NULL` . I want to remove the entire row even one of the columns contains inf, -inf value

Comment: Yes, I removed the comment. Don't think the `!is.na` is needed, since `is.finite(NA)` returns `FALSE`.

Answer (score 5):

It took me awhile to work this out for **dplyr 1.0.0** so i thought i would put up the new version of @sbha solutions using `c_across` since `filter_all`, `filter_if` are getting deprecated.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(a = c(1, 2, 3, NA), b = c(5, Inf, 8, 8), c = c(9, 10, Inf, 11), d = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
#       a     b     c d    
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1     5     9 a    
# 2     2   Inf    10 b    
# 3     3     8   Inf c    
# 4    NA     8    11 d 

df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  filter(!all(is.infinite(c_across(where(is.numeric)))))
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
# # Rowwise: 
#       a     b     c d    
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1     5     9 a    
# 2     2   Inf    10 b    
# 3     3     8   Inf c    
# 4    NA     8    11 d 

df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  filter(!any(is.infinite(c_across(where(is.numeric)))))
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
# # Rowwise: 
#       a     b     c d    
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1     5     9 a    
# 2    NA     8    11 d 

df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  filter(!any(is.infinite(c_across(a:c))))

# # A tibble: 2 x 4
# # Rowwise: 
#       a     b     c d    
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1     5     9 a    
# 2    NA     8    11 d
```

To be honest I think @sbha answer is simpler!

Answer (score 4):

To keep the rows without `Inf` we can do:

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(x) all(is.finite(x))), ]
```

Also `NA`s are handled by this because of:
a rowindex with value `NA` will remove this row in the result.

Also rows with `NaN` are not in the result.

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0:9, NA, -Inf, Inf, NaN),  20*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
df2 <- df[apply(df, 1, function(x) all(is.finite(x))), ]
```

Here are the results of the different `is.~`-functions:

```
x <- c(42, NA, NaN, Inf)
is.finite(x)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
is.na(x)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
is.nan(x)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df[!is.infinite(df$x),]
```

wherein x is the column of df that contains the infinite values. The first answer posted was contingent on rowsums but for my own problem, the df had columns which could not be added.

Comment: This one is the fastest

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and none of the above solutions worked for me. I used the following to remove rows with +/-Inf in columns 15 and 16 of my dataframe.

```
d<-subset(c, c[,15:16]!="-Inf") 
e<-subset(d, d[,15:16]!="Inf")
```

Answer (score 1):

I consider myself new to coding and I couldn't get the recommendations above to work with my code.

I found a less complicated way to reduce a dataframe with 2 lines, first by replacing Inf with Na, then by selecting rows with complete data:

```
Df[sapply(Df, is.infinite)] <- NA
Df<-Df[complete.cases(Df), ]
```